# SSRS Report Manager not displaying entire description in List View

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, ssrs-2017

We recently upgraded to SQL Server 2017 from 2012 for reporting services.  On the report manager, we try to include a description for each report because it is searchable and useful to the end user.

The description is getting cutoff in 2017.  In an earlier version of SSRS (2012), the full description would be visible and would wrap to new lines if necessary.  Is that a configurable option that I just haven't found yet?

What it looks like in 2017:

[image: imgr link]

**Note:** I understand that I can right-click on a report and it will display the full description or I can go to "Manage" it and see the full report.  We would like to see the full description for *all* reports on the page in list view instead of one at a time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems it is by design , and there is not a variable method to change of the width of the description column in ssrs web portal. You could change the width in web element from browser's development tools, while it would restored when your refresh.
You could create a new website like ssrs web portal via ssrs rest api or soap api on your demand.
You could check the project sample [here](https://github.com/Microsoft/Reporting-Services/tree/master/APISamples/typescript).